# SQL Migration Error, SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: laravel

**Error: SQLSTATE[42000]:** Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `subscriptions` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,  `month` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `price`  int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, status tinyint not null default '1', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I have applied this code given below:

````
    {
        Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('month',4);
            $table->integer('price',7);
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

**You can't set a size on integers.**

It should be like this:

```
 $table->integer('month');
 $table->integer('price');
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you can't set size on integers second instead of tinyInteger use boolean

```
    {
        Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('month');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and I would suggest using decimal for price because it may contain a decimal places

```
table->decimal('price', 10, 6)
```